# Misrepresented Property

Tags: real-estate

Suppose someone bought a home that was listed as a two-family property by a real estate broker.  That is how the listing read.  However, the house was no longer a two-family property when the purchase was made because it was not grandfathered in when the owner did not start renovations within a certain time period.  Wht laws, if any, did the seller or agent violate? Has the purchaser any recourse?

Comment: For what it is worth, the case you describe is far from open and shut.

Comment: Depending on where you bought this, your title company is probably the people you would sue, in most States you buy title insurance for something like this.

Comment: I have edited this, and I think it is no longer a request for specific legal advice. If closed, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: In what jurisdiction would this take place? What country, and if a federal country, what province or state? Laws on such matters differ widely.